# This code counts every single view on my WP posts. How do I make it count unique views (exclude page refreshes)

Tags: php, wordpress

The code below counts all page refreshes, how do I make it only count unique views? Right now if I refreshed the page 50 times, it'd add 50 more views, I dont want that.

```
function getPostViews($postID){
$count_key = 'post_views_count';
$count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
if($count==''){
    delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
    add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');
    return "0 View";
  }
 return $count.' Views';
}
function setPostViews($postID) {
    $count_key = 'post_views_count';
    $count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
    if($count==''){
        $count = 0;
        delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
        add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');
    }else{
        $count++;
            update_post_meta($postID, $count_key, $count);
    }
}
// Remove issues with prefetching adding extra views
remove_action( 'wp_head', 'adjacent_posts_rel_link_wp_head', 10, 0);
```

Comment: You would need to wrap this in some sort of check for IP having already been counted. Using $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] & $postID with a cross-reference DB table. Or you could just use a plugin? Like - Posts Unique View Counter

Comment: What about using a cookie? If cookie exists, don't count.